# How can I update an array of two Date() objects in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm sending an array of dates parsed to the popular ISO format (8601,) to my server as strings.

In my mongoose model I have an array specified in my schema for 2 date objects:

```
availability: [
      {
        from: {
          type: Date,
        },
        to: {
          type: Date,
        },
      },
    ],
```

I am trying to populate the array from my controller, like so:

```
const updateAvailability = async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.user.admin) {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json({ message: "Not authorized." });
  }
  try {
    const admin = await User.findOne({ admin: true });

    const d1 = new Date(req.body[0]);
    const d2 = new Date(req.body[1]);
   

    admin.availability = [d1, d2];
    console.log(admin.availability);
    admin.save();
    
    return res
      .status(200)
      .json({ message: "Availability updated." });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

The output I'm getting from the console.log is:

```
[0] [
[0]   { _id: new ObjectId("63f14761ad66201dd83b43e3") },
[0]   { _id: new ObjectId("63f14761ad66201dd83b43e4") }
[0] ]
```

The dates are not on here!

Can anybody tell me the correct way of doing this?

Thanks for reading.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Could you try this `admin.availability = [{from: d1}, {to:  d2}];`?

Comment: I tried that already. Same output in console. Thanks though

Comment: What do you get if you print the value of `admin` after the `findOne` query?

Comment: sorry, not the same output. its better, but now it's an array of objects. I wanted an array of dates...

Comment: For that, try updating your Mongoose model. Currently, your model is an array of objects. So, try something like `availability: [Date]`.

Comment: yeah, okay. Thanks... is there a way to limit the array length?

Comment: There is nothing that comes out of the box. You will need to write your own validator for that field.